# How to include html div or php into PHPMailer success message?

Tags: php

I want to includ HTML div or php page to display in the confirmation msg in PHPMailer, here is the code:

```
if (!$mail->send()) {
$msg .= "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
$msg .= "Message sent! Please read the information bellow.";   
// here I want to display php include or html div   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if (!$mail->send()) {
$msg .= "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
$msg .= "<span id='id_name'>Message sent! Please read the information bellow.</span>";   
// here I want to display php include or html div   
}
```

Now you can css your `#id_name` as you want

Comment: It is working this way, but also I want to include a whole php page.

Comment: what do you mean a whole php page?

Comment: okay i understand, you can use`header` to redirect  to the php page you what . Put the `header("Location: success.php");  exit;`  where you success message is. i think that what you want

Comment: I dont want to redirect to another page, but I want to display a ready php page inside this part under the message :)

Comment: @Isabella, just  `include` your page at the success section.